# python pandas dataframe set one column as key and rows as value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and i wanted to convert into dictionary.

```
email,account_no,cust_id
xyz,123,456
abc,789,654
nbc,345,907
```

From the df i wanted the email to be as key and other two column as value. Needed output like

```
{xyz:[123,456],
abc:[789,654],
nbc:[345,907]}
```

Can anybody let me know how this can be achieved ?.

Comment: What have you tried?  What were the results?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
df.set_index('email').T.to_dict('list')

# output

{'xyz': [123, 456], 'abc': [789, 654], 'nbc': [345, 907]}
```

Comment: Thanks Anders, i have another query. Is it possible to get the columns account_no,cust_id as a string instead of list  e.g. {'xyz': 123, 456, 'abc': 789, 654, 'nbc': 345, 907}

Comment: Try `{k:', '.join(map(str,v)) for k, v in output.items()}`. Gives `{'xyz': '123, 456', 'abc': '789, 654', 'nbc': '345, 907'}`.